# How to get geographical coordinates in google maps API V2 android using an string address?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I´m designing an android app that locate places, these places are in a database in a server but I only have the name and location of the place, so I need to locate it in my app and put a *marker* there. It's posible to get coordinates only with address or, Do I need to redo my database adding fields with latitude and longitude?

Comment: agree with anton you need an api to get `lat, lng`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) class to do a look-up of the addresses you have, and then populate the map with Markers using the `LanLng` objects that are returned.

Note that the `Geocoder` class will not be able to geocode every address, but it will be successful for most of them if they are in the correct format.

Taking code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30521933/how-to-get-latitude-longitude-from-more-than-500-addresses) as a guide, I just got this simple example working.

I created a custom class that stores location name, location address, and a `LatLng` object to store the lat/lon.

For this simple example, I just used three addresses.

Here is the full class code:

```
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }


    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }


    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        List<CustomLocation> custLocs = new ArrayList<CustomLocation>();

        //Testing with three addresses
        custLocs.add(new CustomLocation("location 1", "100 market street san francisco ca"));
        custLocs.add(new CustomLocation("location 2", "200 market street san francisco ca"));
        custLocs.add(new CustomLocation("location 3", "300 market street san francisco ca"));


        //set the location for each item in the list
        for (CustomLocation custLoc : custLocs){
            custLoc.setLocation(getSingleLocationFromAddress(custLoc.address));
        }

        //draw the Marker for each item in the list
        for (CustomLocation custLoc : custLocs){
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(custLoc.latLng)
                    .title(custLoc.name).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA)));
        }
    }

    //method to do a lookup on the address
    public LatLng getSingleLocationFromAddress(String strAddress)
    {
        Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> address = null;
        Address location = null;
        LatLng temp = null;
        String strAddresNew = strAddress.replace(",", " ");
        try
        {
            address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddresNew, 1);
            if (!address.isEmpty())
            {
                location = address.get(0);
                location.getLatitude();
                location.getLongitude();
                temp = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                Log.d("Latlng : ", temp + "");
            }
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return temp;
    }

    //class to hold the name and address and location
    public static class CustomLocation{

        public String name;
        public String address;
        public LatLng latLng;
        public CustomLocation(String n, String a){
            name = n;
            address = a;
        }
        public void setLocation(LatLng ll){
            latLng = ll;
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It really works easy, Thanks! Obviously I have to take care in the addresses that I use because it can give a wrong address, right?

Comment: @ReneLimon No problem! I believe the only thing you need to worry about is the LatLng coming back null for some addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a request to google maps API to get possible addresses by a address string. Check this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#geocoding).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Geocoder class, which will return the latitude and longitude for a given address in a specified format.However a specified format has to be followed for the address name.
Check out for more information on this from the below link :-
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder