# How can I get position in google map?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, latitude-longitude

I want to find position of location(with latitude and longitude).

I try to get the (latitude, longitude) of left-top and right-bottom points of map and lerp to calculate the position.

However, I don't know coordinate of left-top and right-bottom points.
How can I get or calculate them?

Comment: so do you want to find where the center of the map is pointed at or the bounding box of the map?

Comment: Some days ago I do the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30740306/how-to-get-geographical-coordinates-in-google-maps-api-v2-android-using-an-strin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Center:

```
map.getCameraPosition().target;
```

Bounds:

```
LatLngBounds curScreen = map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
```

Where you then access left-top and right-bottom points using:

```
curScreen.northeast
```

and

```
curScreen.southwest
```

Comment: How to get bottomLeft and TopRight?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [VisibleRegion](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/VisibleRegion) class.

From a `MapFragment` you can use:

```
VisibleRegion visibleRegion = getMap().getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
```